# FTP, SSH, VNC, ETC; All in One Environment?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

I have a virtual private server, and I find myself constantly cycling through SSH tunnels in my Linux terminal to the server, then exiting to get to my current systems shell, then logging on to a FTP client for file transfer, researching issues via my browser, then sorting files via my file manager on my linux laptop, plugging in random usb drives, then I end up needing to log on to my server via VNC over a gui just to simply click a JavaScript only link in a browser to download a file, and on and on...

It gets complicated, I end up having TONS of windows open, and never end up staying on the same program for more than a couple minutes. I find it more time consuming than necessary, and I just came to the conclusion that there HAS to be an "All in One" software that combines all these tasks somehow? If not, I have a nice starting point for something. ;)

Does anyone know of such a thing? Or maybe another way one would recommend that would decrease the cycling and wastes of time?

Preferably I would need this type of software or environment for Linux, and possibly Windows.

Some extra features would be nice as well.

Any thoughts on this guys?

Answer (score 0):

I use OnlineVNC - http://www.onlinevnc.com. It has FTP File Transfer and VNC Remote Desktop in one bottle. Maybe it will be useful for you too - http://www.onlinevnc.com/support/configuring-ftp-based-file-transfer.html.